# Erroneous points produced on convex hull despite following Graham scan

Tags: java, algorithm, convex-hull, grahams-scan

I've essentially followed the [wikipedia entry for Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) every step of the way as I've coded this little convex hull visualizer. It generally works as intended, but at much higher input sizes there are often erroneous points.

The program starts by filling an `ArrayList<Point>` with a given number of randomly generated `Point` objects. It then finds the `Point` with the lowest `y`. If multiple `Point` objects share the lowest value, then the one with the lowest `x` is used.

Next, it generates an `ArrayList<Double>` of angles of every `Point` relative to the specific `Point` found above. It quicksorts these angles and their corresponding `Point` objects to produce an `ArrayList<Point>` with sorted values.

The next step is where I believe my problem lies. First, I make a copy of the `ArrayList<Point>` and call it `edges` (note that if I was not using the original `ArrayList<Point>` for visualization, cloning would be unnecessary) For any three ordered `Point` objects in `edges` we'll call `A`, `B,` and `C`, if from `AB` to `BC` there is a right turn, then `B` should be excluded from the hull and is removed from `edges`. I determine whether the turn is right or left by taking the z-value of the cross product (negative z means `AB` to `BC` is a right turn). The program removes any points which causes right turns and carries on.

```
// loops through the orders points. any time a right turn is
// encountered, the middle point is removed
edges = new ArrayList<Point>();
edges.addAll(points);
boolean changed = true;
while (changed) {
    changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size() - 2; i++) {
        if (isRightTurn(edges.get(i), edges.get(i + 1),
                edges.get(i + 2))) {
            edges.remove(i + 1);
            changed = true;
            i--;
        }
    }
    if (isRightTurn(edges.get(edges.size() - 2),
        edges.get(edges.size() - 1), edges.get(0))) {
        edges.remove(edges.size() - 1);
        changed = true;
    }
}


// uses the z-value of the cross product of AB and AC (ABxAC) to determine
// the direction of the turn.
public static boolean isRightTurn(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    if ((b.getX() - a.getX()) * (c.getY() - a.getY())
            - (b.getY() - a.getY()) * (c.getX() - a.getX()) < 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I mainly added the `changed` variable for the sake of looping through multiple times just to verify in case something was skipped over. However, the error still persists. Sometimes, it works as intended. [image: Successful convex hull]

However, frequently there are at least a few incorrect `Point` objects.[image: Unsuccessful convex hull]

Now what I'm noticing is that up until the left turn occurs, there are multiple `Points` which properly turn left, but are still erroneous because they ultimately lie inside what should be the convex hull. Could this be an issue of backtracking? I feel like the repeated looping through should catch these cases.

Comment: You want a `while` loop, not an `if` construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right way to build the convex hull after sorting the points:

```
onHull = new List()
for p <- sorted list of points(including the first one)
    while onHull.size() >= 2 && isRight(onHull[onHull.size() - 2], onHull[onHull.size() - 1], p) 
        onHull.popBack()
    onHull.pushBack(p)
return onHull
```